# LibreOffice Calc: How to get total for HH:MM:SS cells for graveyard using 24 hour clock

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a week. From B28 to H28 I have start time. B29 to H29 I have End time the next morning. From B30 to H30 I have actual time from each day with this formula: =(24-B28) +B29. This gives me the correct time for each day. Then on I29 I try to Sum the week but it won't sum correctly. So on the Sum cell I have =SUM(B30:H30) and I have format on the cell by Clicking format from the upper drop down and select Cell, Select Numbers Tab in Dialog Box, Select Time Category in left window and Select 876613:37:46:00 format. Click ok. Example: Start time: 21:00, End Time: 07:00. So, Actual time is 10:00 Hours. But, when I sum just one day it shows: 4018:00:00:00. Hope someone can help or at least smack me and show me what's wrong with it.

Comment: It's hard to visualize data. Please provide a mockup of the data, and look for ways to clarify the question, possibly by adding formating?

Comment: Welcome! Just a light smack: format the cells as regular numbers. You will see that `21:00` has turned into `0.875` - this is the part of the day that corresponds to 9 pm. And `07:00` turned into `0.291667`. And here is the source of the misunderstanding - it's 7 a.m. the [**next day**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/summing-time-durations-not-times/66176), that is, the cell should contain `1.291667` - the number before the dot is the number of full days. Try to include all time values along with date `2022-05-10 21:00` and `2022-05-11 07:00` and the calculations will be carried out correctly

Comment: Solved it. Took the 24 hour from the equation and put it in another cell and formatted it as time. Thanks!!